# Autosar watchdog utility

Tags: watchdog, autosar

in a safe Autosar project suppose I configure watchdog deadline monitoring or flow control.

if the watchdog detects the deadline of flow violation, the ECU resets. when the violation is persistent, the ECU reset is persistent

what's the value added by the watchdog in this case? instead of ECU freezing, the ECU is resetting indefinitely?

Comment: You should consider reading the EcuM Startup/Shutdown sequences and EcuM ResetReason / WakeupSourceType, (optional) EcuM_LoopDetection callout. There is a possibility in certain conditions per defined APIs the shutdown reason, source and target, and to determine in startup such things and map them to EcuM statemachine. In worst case, EcuM can e.g. send a CL30 to sleep, or just stay in silent state and not go further in Init / Startup. Such state could e.g. switch the controller to low-power modes or reduce clocks etc.

Comment: The reason to use the Watchdog (WdgM->WdgIf->Wdg) is, to bring your ECU back into a runnable and consistent state. If high prio tasks and/or ISRs deadlock your system or an out-of-order task timing, how would you bring back outputs and actuators into a safe state?

Answer (score 0):

SW should be well tested during development to make sure no resets, deadlocks or high cpu-load.
If a problem happened during production WDG would be your last line of defense so it will perform a reset to get out of this state and start over everything.
In most safe projects I am aware of, init state is considered as safe state because you initialize all IOs to default values "e.g. engine->stop".

If you have worries from such a situation you can set a flag once WdgM detects violation and save it in non-initialized ram section then check it in startup.